# Include files in SOURCES.txt

Tags: python, setuptools

Is there an easy way to include files into the SOURCES.txt in the install command class? I am using the following in the setup.py file:

```
cmdclass={
            'develop': PostDevelopCommand,
            'install': PostInstallCommand,
        },

 class PostInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        # PUT YOUR POST-INSTALL SCRIPT HERE or CALL A FUNCTION
        install.run(self)
```